# Pythonic Logic - Seeking a more efficient approach to multiple if statements that check a list of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, performance, logic

I've been working on a simple GUI within Python to pull data from PowerBi, that looks similar to the image below:

[image]

The app works fine, however I am looking to improve it's efficiency.

The checkbar is produced with the following code:

```
Datasets = [
    'Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3',
    'Option 4', 'Option 5',
    'Option 6', 'Option 7',
    'Option 8', 'Option 9']

print(os.getcwd())
cwd = os.getcwd

class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vars = []
        for pick in picks:
            var = IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var, width=22, anchor='w')
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
            self.vars.append(var)
    def state(self):
        return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("PowerBI Data Collector")
    root.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(
        file="Icon/Directory"))
    responseLabel = Label(root)
    
    # Check
    data1 = Checkbar(root, Datasets[0:3], anchor=W)
    data2 = Checkbar(root, Datasets[3:6], anchor=W)
    data3 = Checkbar(root, Datasets[6:9], anchor=W)

    data1.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1)
    data1.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=1)
    data2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1)
    data2.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=1)
    data3.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1)
    data3.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=1)
```

Based on the user's choice's from the checkbars, a list of 0's and 1's is produced describing the state of the input, using the code:

```
dataState = list(data1.state())
dataState.extend(list(data2.state()))
dataState.extend(list(data3.state()))
```

As such, if option 2 and option 4 is chosen, the dataState will read: `[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]`

From here there are a number of `if` statements that check for whether their respective integers from the list is a 1, and if so calls the respective function to pull the data specific to that checkbox from PowerBi. A few of which are detailed below:

```
            if dataState == [0]*len(Datasets): # nothing
                responseLabel.destroy()
                responseLabel = Label(text = "Please select from the checklist above")
                responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

            if dataState[0] == 1: # option2
                # Response Label
                responseLabel.destroy()
                try:
                    uf.option2(User=userDetails[0], Pass = userDetails[1])
                    responseLabel = Label(text = "All data downloaded")
                    responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
                except:
                    responseLabel = Label(text = "option 1 data download failed")
                    responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

            if dataState[1] == 1: # option1
                # Response Label
                responseLabel.destroy()
                try:
                    uf.option1(User=userDetails[0], Pass = userDetails[1])
                    responseLabel = Label(text = "All data downloaded")
                    responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
                except:
                    responseLabel = Label(text = "option 2 data download failed")
                    responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
```

This is quite inefficient and was fine when there were only 3 options, but now there are 9, and more are expected to be added. I was thinking of converting the `if` statement section to a `for` loop, and the iteration of the loop that corresponded to a 1 within the list called a specific function, but this too seemed inefficient so I pose the question here, with the hopes of finding a better suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're on the right track with the ```for``` loop. Make each option a function, put them in a list, and iterate through ```dataState```; if ```dateState[index]``` is ```1```, call the function at that ```index``` in the functions list.

Comment: @sj95126 I hadn't thought of loading the functions into a list, that should work nicely, thanks very much!

Comment: @sj95126 if you copy and paste your answer into an official answer i'll mark it as accepted, as this has worked nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, scalable option would be to make each option's code into a function and put them into a `list` or `tuple`, e.g.:

```
optionFunc = (opt1, opt2, opt3, etc.)
```

Then you could iterate through `dataState` and call the associated function, something like:

```
for index, state in enumerate(dataState):
    if state:
        option_func[index](responseLabel)
```

There may be a more sophisticated way to do this, maybe the GUI code you're using can associate labels with the checkboxes that you can use as dictionary indexes, but this would be the general idea.

(I put `optionFunc` in `camelCase` to be consistent with the rest of your code, but in Python `snake_case` would be the preferred form)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between the code under the if of option1 and option2 is the function being called: uf.option1 vs uf.option2 and also in the failure print. this duplication of code can be avoided.

first, use a dictionary to map between the option and its function in uf:

```
option_funcs={1: uf.option1, 2: uf.option2 ...}
```

then convert the code in your "if"s to a function that gets an integer option as parameter and calls the relevant uf.option

```
def download_data(option):
    responseLabel.destroy()
    try:
        option_funcs[option](User=userDetails[0], Pass = userDetails[1])
        responseLabel = Label(text = "All data downloaded")
        responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
    except:
        responseLabel = Label(text = "option {} data download failed".format(option))
        responseLabel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
```

finally, replace all of your ifs with a for that iterates over dataState:

```
for count, value in enumerate(dataState, start=1):
    if value: download_data(count)
```